# How to validate PGP public key written by a user?

Tags: javascript, validation, pgp

I am trying to validate PGP public key input in the form.

I know that the public PGP key starts with `-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----` and ends with `-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----`. So I have created the validation function `isValidPublicPGP`.

```
function isValidPublicPGP(pubKey) {
    if (!pubKey.startsWith("-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----")) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!pubKey.endsWith("-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----")) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But it is a very primitive validator. Maybe there is some library that can validate the public PGP key. Or maybe you know some other rules that indicate PGP public key is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At best, your method could only validate the schema of a public key, not the key itself. For instance, if you knew that all valid public keys consisted of 56 alphanumeric characters surrounded by the header and footer

`-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----`

`-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----`

You might be tempted to call the following a decent validation function

```
function validatePGP(key) {
    return !!key.match(/^(-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----)\s?\w{56}\s?(-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----)$/)
}
```

This would properly validate that a key follows the defined schema, but it doesn't mean the key is valid, only that it could be. There is nothing stopping me from putting in a key like this

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
thisisnotavalidkeybutthereisnowayforyoutoknowthatisthere
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

The function would validate this and say it was a good key, but obviously that is not the case. The right way to validate this key would be to compute its signature and compare that signature against that of the official key on a known keyserver, or a known piece of software signed by the key. If they match, you have a valid key that has not been tampered with.

This can all be handled client or server side with the `openpgp` port to javscript that be downloaded from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openpgp), but if you are going to be using this for actively encrypting and decrypting files, I'd strongly recommend this be done server side.